# NaN assigned with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, nan, parseint

I'm trying to add an `innerHTML` value to another `innerHTML` after converting each of them to `int` and then assign the total to another `innerhtml` so that it can be printed out using javascript

I have tried `parseInt` and `parseFloat`, but it didn't work out for me.

Actually after I converted `innerHTML` to `int` I got "NaN" instead of getting a number.

Here is my code :

```
var Sum = parseInt(document.getElementById('fir').innerHTML) +
          parseInt(document.getElementById('sec').innerHTML);

setTimeout(function func(){ch1.innerHTML=Sum;},2500);
```

Now the `Sum` in the last line inside the function `func()` should be an integer, but unfortunately it's not, in my case it's equal to "NaN", why is this?

**Edit:** 
**Every Thing regarding fir & sec**

```
<body>
<h1 id="fir"></h1>
<h2 id="sec"></h2>

<script>
  var x = document.getElementById("fir")
  x.style.position = "absolute";
  x.style.left = 770;
  x.style.top = 315;

  var z = document.getElementById("sec")
  z.style.position = "absolute";
  z.style.left = 930;
  z.style.top = 315;

  setTimeout(function a(){x.innerHTML=Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);},1000);

  setTimeout(function b(){z.innerHTML=Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);},2000);

</script>

</body>
```

Comment: What types of element are 'fir' and 'sec'? Print out there innerHTML as well using `console.log()`.

Comment: Well, what kind of elements are `fir` and `sec`, are they `input` elements? If that's the case you should be using their `value` attribute instead of `innerHTML`.

Comment: *"Actually after i converted innerHTML to int i got NaN instead of getting a number"* Great! That tells you what the problem is: The `innerHTML` of at least one of those two cannot be converted into an int directly. So now you just have to look at those two values in the debugger and see what the problem is. (BTW: `NaN` is, technically, a number -- despite the name!)

Answer (score 0):

Try starting as a numeric value

```html
    <h1 id="fir">0</h1>
    <h2 id="sec">0</h2>
```

You are suming the values before the timeouts, you should wrap your suming in a function and call it right after setting the values example:

```js
    function applySUM()
    {
        var Sum = parseInt(document.getElementById('fir').innerHTML) +
        parseInt(document.getElementById('sec').innerHTML);    
        ch1.innerHTML=Sum; //removed the timer to apply the calculation
    }

    setTimeout(function(){
        x.innerHTML=Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
        applySUM();
    },1000);

    setTimeout(function(){
        z.innerHTML=Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
        applySUM();
    },2000);
```